# Laravel - Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\jairusreport\resources\views\layouts\header.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

I have an application on Laravel 5.8. Each time the user stays long on the application, this error come up

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\jairusreport\resources\views\layouts\header.blade.php)

[image: session error]

For some days no I've been battling with a particular error and it has really wasted my time. I have done the screenshot of the error below.

Auth/LoginController

```
class LoginController extends Controller   
{
use AuthenticatesUsers;
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

protected function hasTooManyLoginAttempts ($request) {
    $maxLoginAttempts = 2;
    $lockoutTime = 5; // 5 minutes
    return $this->limiter()->tooManyAttempts(
        $this->throttleKey($request), $maxLoginAttempts, $lockoutTime
    );
}  

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

public function logout()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    Log::info('User Logged Out. ', [$user]);
    Auth::logout();
    Session::flush();

    return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/login');
}    
}
```

What is the cause of the problem. What do I do to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There will be two possible things

1. Either there is no field in database whose name ie name
2. Or you are not logged in.

For checking whether user is logged in or not

```
if(Auth::check())
{
   echo Auth::user()->id;
 }
```

Check the above condition & don't forgot to add this in user model

```
class user
{
   protected $fillable = [
    'name'
   ];
 }
```

Comment: `Auth::user()->name` doesn't throw an error if there's no column `name` on the `users` table; it just echos out (or returns) `""`. The issue is `Auth::user()` is returning `null`. Point 2 is correct, point 1 is not.

Comment: 1. The field (name) exist in the database.    2. I am logged in because it displays the name after log in

Comment: Ok, Then you can check my updated answer. if it is working fine then check session lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses sessions to keep track of authenticated users. Its possible that the sessions are timing out, and the user is being logged out.

To avoid this causing issues in your views, I'd advise null checking `Auth::user()` or making use of `Auth::check()` with a blade if-block.

If you want to modify the SESSION_LIFETIME, take a look at `config/session.php`